# cannot find custom message groovy

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone,

I'm working to define a custom message in ROS Groovy.  I've followed the tutorial and updated my CMakeLists to innclude a custom message with the following changes in my package:

```
  7 find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation)

 19  add_message_files(
 20    FILES
 21    data_logger_measurement.msg
 22  )

 32  generate_messages(
 33    DEPENDENCIES
 34    std_msgs
 35  )

 44 catkin_package(
 45   INCLUDE_DIRS include
 46 #  LIBRARIES tempSensorInterface 
 47   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation 
 48   DEPENDS system_lib message_runtime 
 49 )
```

I've also created a msg directory and placed the following data_logger_measurement.msg file in that directory:

```
Header header
float32 pressure # [C]
float32 temperature # [kPa]
```

(This msg is in the same package as my executable that I'm creating.)

unfortunately, when my executable includes this message with:

```
#include<temp_sensor_interface/data_logger_measurement.h>
```

and when I call "make" in my build folder, I get a message that there's

No such file or directory

Am I missing another step that creates such a header file in groovy? Thanks for lending a hand on this problem!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52687/cannot-find-custom-message-groovy/) by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, it seems there is at least a small bug in genmsg: https://github.com/ros/genmsg/issues/16

This bug means you have to double-check all filenames.

If your include line is:

```
#include <temp_sensor_interface/data_logger_measurement.h>
```

then make sure to check this file exists at:

```
ls devel/include/temp_sensor_interface
```

in your workspace devel folder.

Also make sure the name of your package really is temp_sensor_interface

When you change the name of the .msg file, you need to also change the CMakeLists.txt, even if it had been correct. (Make any change, like adding a blank line). Else for the .msg file, no new message will be generated. Another way to make sure, is to delete your build and devel folders, and start catkin_make again.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2013-01-18**:
My mistake in posting the wrong info; my .msg file and .h  are actually titled the same, but that definitely could've caused it. (I've changed the initial post above so that they reflect what my problem actually looks like.)

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2013-01-19**:
Thanks!  Recreating the devel folder worked!

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-19**:
@Poofjunior if the answer solves your issue, please click the check sign so that others can easily tell that this issue is solved.